# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when loading English class

Tags: java

I am simple trying to Instantiate English class

```
   English e = new English();
   e.setVisible(true);
```

Every time I run the program and click a button i get error.
I have loaded all the correct jar files and rechecked all the code to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

//here is the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: EntranceExamination/English
at EntranceExamination.LogicalReasoning.btnContinueActionPerformed(LogicalReasoning.java:1005)
at EntranceExamination.LogicalReasoning.access$1600(LogicalReasoning.java:22)
at EntranceExamination.LogicalReasoning$15.actionPerformed(LogicalReasoning.java:335)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EntranceExamination.English
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 39 more
```

Comment: Show a minimal example of where you are seeing the error.

Comment: Your runtime classpath is incomplete.

Comment: what do you mean by incomplete sir can you please elaborate? @Andersen

Comment: Rintime Classpath`C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\modules\ext\AbsoluteLayout.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\db\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\opencv\build\java\opencv-411.jar;C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Capstone1\build\classes`   Compile Classpath `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\modules\ext\AbsoluteLayout.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\db\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\opencv\build\java\opencv-411.jar`